# How do I annotate an implicit parameter in a stub

Tags: java, checker-framework

I'm trying to use the Nullness Checker to build a subclass of JPanel.

```
class MyView<R extends @NonNull Object> extends JPanel {
  // ...
  // constructor calls this method:
  @RequiresNonNull({"labelPanel", "fieldPanel", "checkBoxPanel"})
  private void makeTopPanel(@UnderInitialization MyView<R> this) {
    JPanel topPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    topPanel.add(labelPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
    topPanel.add(fieldPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    topPanel.add(checkBoxPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);

    // Error here: [method.invocation.invalid] call to add(java.awt.Component,java.lang.Object)
    // not allowed on the given receiver.
    add(topPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    setBorder(new MatteBorder(1, 0, 0, 0, Color.black));
  }
}
```

The error message says this:

```
error: [method.invocation.invalid] call to add(java.awt.Component,java.lang.Object) not allowed 
on the given receiver.
  found   : @UnderInitialization @NonNull Container
  required: @Initialized @NonNull Container
```

The problem seems to be that the add method assumes the `this` is initialized. But it's very safe to call a Container's add method inside a constructor.  So to prevent this error, I want to create a stub file with an annotated implicit parameter:

```
package java.awt;
public class Container extends Component {
  public void add(@UnknownInitialization Container, @NonNull Component, @NonNull Object);
}
```

It doesn't seem to recognize the `add()` method here as the `java.awt.Container.add(Component, Object)` method.

Here's the complete stub file:

```
import org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.Nullable;
import org.checkerframework.checker.initialization.qual.UnknownInitialization;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;

package javax.swing;

public class Timer {
  public Timer(int delay, @Nullable ActionListener listener);
}

public class JOptionPane {
  public static void showMessageDialog(@Nullable Component parentComponent,
          Object message, String title, int messageType)
          throws HeadlessException;
}

package java.awt;
public class Container extends Component {
  public void setBorder(@UnknownInitialization JComponent this, @Nullable Border border);
  public void add(@UnknownInitialization Container this, @NonNull Component, @NonNull Object);
}
```

I know I can suppress the warning with an annotation, but the stub file feels like a cleaner approach. Is there any way to fix this stub file?

Comment: The answer below is correct. However, I should mention that I needed to add <showWarnings>true</showWarnings> to the configuration section of the maven compiler plugin, in order to get error messages for my stub file. As of this writing, you won't find that in the checker framework manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems.

The first problem is that **your stub file is malformed**.

The line

```
  public void add(@UnknownInitialization Container this, @NonNull Component, @NonNull Object);
```

should be

```
  public void add(@UnknownInitialization Container this, @NonNull Component comp, @NonNull Object constraints);
```

because Java method declarations require formal parameter names.

Furthermore, it was missing an `import` statement:

```
import org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.NonNull;
```

The second problem is that **you must not have been passing an `-Astubs=...` command-line argument**, or you would have received warnings about your malformed stub file.  (You didn't say how you invoked `javac`, which would have helped to diagnose your problem.)

When I corrected these problems, the Checker Framework worked as expected.
Running the command

```
$CHECKERFRAMEWORK/checker/bin/javac -processor nullness -g MyView.java
```

issues the warning, and

```
$CHECKERFRAMEWORK/checker/bin/javac -processor nullness -g MyView.java -Astubs=mystub.astub
```

issues no warning.

Corrected files (that is, they are complete and more minimal) appear below.

MyView.java:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import org.checkerframework.checker.initialization.qual.UnderInitialization;

class MyView extends JPanel {

  MyView() {
    makeTopPanel();
  }

  private void makeTopPanel(@UnderInitialization MyView this) {
    JPanel topPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    add(topPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
  }
}
```

mystub.astub:

```
import org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.NonNull;
import org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.Nullable;
import org.checkerframework.checker.initialization.qual.UnknownInitialization;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;

package javax.swing;

public class Timer {
  public Timer(int delay, @Nullable ActionListener listener);
}

public class JOptionPane {
  public static void showMessageDialog(@Nullable Component parentComponent,
          Object message, String title, int messageType)
          throws HeadlessException;
}

package java.awt;
public class Container extends Component {
  public void setBorder(@UnknownInitialization JComponent this, @Nullable Border border);
  public void add(@UnknownInitialization Container this, @NonNull Component comp, @NonNull Object constraints);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. You are right that my stub file was malformed, but I was invoking the stubs file correctly. I never saw a "malformed stubs file" message. I just tested this by 1) introducing a nullness problem in a standard java API, 2) Verifying that it produced a compiler error, 3) adding a stub for the method, 4) verifying that my stub fixed the error, and 5) deleting a parameter name from the new stub. With the new, malformed stub in the stub file, I get the compiler error again, but I get no warning that the stub was malformed. I tried this under versions checker framework 3.1.0 and 3.2.0.

Comment: I'd be happy to provide a use case if you need one.

Comment: It's odd you didn't see the error message about your malformed stub file.  Perhaps you and I were invoking the compiler differently.  Stack Overflow isn't a good place to supply a detailed bug report, but could you do so at the [Checker Framework issue tracker](https://github.com/typetools/checker-framework/issues)?

Comment: Done. See Malformed Stub Bug #3132

Comment: Here's a link, for anyone following the conversation: [Checker Framework issue #3132](https://github.com/typetools/checker-framework/issues/3132).

Comment: So I just got an email telling me to turn off the verbose option, and to put `<showWarnings>true</showWarnings>` into the configuration section of the maven compiler plugin. That (along with removing <arg>-verbose</arg>) fixes the problem. I now get very detailed descriptions of the problem with my stubs file.
I would like to suggest that this information belongs in the checker framework Manual. In fact, it should probably be included in the sample code in section 32.11, where it shows how to set up the pom.xml file. The entire checker framework manual makes no mention of showWarnings.

Comment: As noted in the issue thread, this is already done.  No need to say it again here. :-)